# openRTSP default 25fps encoding (not 24)

Tags: linux, encoding, libav, fps, rtsp

I want to capture the RTSP stream from some IP cameras, and after looking around I found 2 great tools to do this: avconv and openRTSP

```
openRTSP -u user password rtsp://10.48.34.125/axis-media/media.amp
avconv -i "rtsp://user:password@10.48.34.125/axis-media/media.amp" -vcodec copy -f mp4 10.48.34.125.mp4
```

but for some voodoo reason when I need to use URLs without an specific extension, such as:

```
rtsp://user:password@10.48.34.46/
```

avconv returns `401 Unauthorized`

so I'm stuck with openRTSP at the moment...

The thing is, unlike avconv, openRTSP outputs a raw file which is encoded to 25fps, which made some of my videos look like they where in fast-forward. I found a (cpu expensive) way to re-encode the file to a closer frame rate to what I need:

```
avconv -r 7 -i video-H264-1 -r 24 -f mp4 10.48.34.28.mp4
```

(in this example I'm forcing the frame rate of the raw file to be 7, and the frame rate of the output file to be 24. I tried using openRTSP build-in flags, but the output file still had a frame rate of 25: `openRTSP -f 7 -u user password rtsp://10.48.34.145/mpeg4/media.3gp`)

Sadly the video looks odd at certain points, and that's because the original stream sometimes has a variable frame rate (for example at night).

My question is, is there some way to deactive this default encondig to 25fps?

And why 25? I mean, isn't the norm 24?

I'm using 2 types of cameras: Axis and Bosch. The ones I'm having problem with are the Bosch cameras.

Comment: Per the note at http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/ , if the SDP specifies a frame rate for the stream, it will be used of the `-f ` parameter value.  It might help to know the model of your IP cameras -- you may be able to set it on the camera side.  Also, 25 fps isn't unusual to find in regions where 720p50 / 1080i50 is the standard for broadcast TV.

Comment: just added which cameras I'm using :) How can I configure the SDP?